# Trying to prove that the expression for the radial component of the acceleration is equal to $\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf v/r$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, vectors, calculus

I am trying to prove that the normal component of acceleration of a particle undergoing a curvilinear motion is equal to
$\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf v/r$.

Here $\mathbf v$ is the velocity of the particle at that instant. And $r$ is the radius of the curvature of the point (which I have taken as $P$ as shown in the picture below) on the trajectory.

I am sharing the picture where I tried to prove the above statement.

[image]

But I got stuck in how to figure out the derivative of the angle $\theta$. The angle made by the tangent at a particular point on the trajectory with the X axis.

Please help me how to proceed after this.

Comment: It's against our rules to post images of text you want to quote. Please type it out instead so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose an origin at the centre of curvature of the curve. Use the unit vectors

$$\mathbf{ \hat r} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta \\
\sin \theta \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{ \hat \theta} = \begin{pmatrix}
-\sin \theta \\
\cos \theta \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$\mathbf r = r \mathbf{ \hat r} $$
by the product and chain rule
$$\dot {\mathbf r} = \dot r \mathbf{ \hat r} +r \dot \theta \mathbf{ \hat \theta} $$
$$\ddot {\mathbf r} = \ddot r \mathbf{ \hat r} +\dot r \dot \theta \mathbf{ \hat \theta}  +\dot r \dot \theta \mathbf{ \hat \theta} + r \ddot \theta \mathbf{ \hat \theta} -  r \dot \theta^2 \mathbf{ \hat r} $$

Since the chosen origin is normal $\ddot r = 0$ and you can read off the normal acceleration $ -  r \dot \theta^2 = -v^2/r.$